# Getting non_field_errors using JSONField()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a **PATCH** request using to the Django Rest Framework but get the following error:

```
{"image_data": [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]
```

I understand that JSONField() could give some issues so I have taken care of that by adding  `to_native` and `from_native`, But, I'm still running into this issue. I don't think `JSONField()` is the problem here at all, but still worth mentioning.

I believe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong in how I am trying to update the related field.

Code below...

**Models:**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, help_text="Item belongs to.")
    image_data = models.ForeignKey("PhotoData", null=True, blank=True)


class PhotoData(models.Model):
    thisdata = JSONField()
```

**Serializers:**

```
class ExternalJSONField(serializers.WritableField):
    def to_native(self, obj):
        return json.dumps(obj)

    def from_native(self, value):
        try:
            val = json.loads(value)
        except TypeError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Could not load json <{}>".format(value)
            )
        return val

class PhotoDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    thisdata = ExternalJSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoData
        fields = ("id", "thisdata")


class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image_data = PhotoDataSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("id","user", "image_data")
```

**PATCH:**

```
> payload = {"image_data": {"thisdata": "{}"}}
> requests.patch("/photo/123/",payload )
```

I have also tried:

```
> payload = {"image_data": [{"thisdata": "{}"}]}
> requests.patch("/photo/123/",payload )
```

But again giving the same error:

**[{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original idea of Django Rest Framework's serialization of relations is to not change values of related fields.
It means that your payload should contain a `pk` of `PhotoData` object, not a dataset for it.
It's like in models you can't assign a dict to a foreign key field.

Good (works only with serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField which contains problems itself):

```
   payload = {"image_data": 2}
```

Bad (not works in DRF by default):

```
   payload = {"image_data": {'thisdata': '{}'}}
```

Actually the data model that you provided doesn't need `PhotoData` at all (you can move `thisdata` field to `Photo`), but let's assume you have a special case even when Zen of Python says `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`.

So, here is some possible ways:

**Using fields serializers (your original way)**

What you want to do now is possible but is very ugly solution.
You may create a `PhotoDataField` (*works for me, but not ready to use code, only for demonstration*)

```
class PhotoDataField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def field_to_native(self, *args):
        """
        Use field_to_native from RelatedField for correct `to_native` result
        """
        return super(serializers.RelatedField, self).field_to_native(*args)

    # Prepare value to output
    def to_native(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, PhotoData):
            return obj.thisdata
        return super(PhotoDataField, self).to_native(obj)

    # Handle input value
    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        try:
            int(data['image_data'])
        except ValueError:
            # Looks like we have a data for `thisdata` field here.
            # So let's do write this to PhotoData model right now.
            # Why? Because you can't do anything with `image_data` in further.
            if not self.root.object.image_data:
                # Create a new `PhotoData` instance and use it.
                self.root.object.image_data = PhotoData.objects.create()
            self.root.object.image_data.thisdata = data['image_data']
            self.root.object.image_data.save()

            return data['image_data']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        # So native behaviour works (e.g. via web GUI)
        return super(PhotoDataField, self).field_from_native(data, files, field_name, into)
```

and use it in `PhotoSerializer`

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image_data = PhotoDataField(read_only=False, source='image_data')

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("id", "user", "image_data")
```

so the request will works well

```
payload = {"image_data": '{}'}
resp = requests.patch(request.build_absolute_uri("/api/photo/1/"), payload)
```

and the "good" request also

```
photodata = PhotoData.objects.get(pk=1)
payload = {"image_data": photodata.pk}
resp = requests.patch(request.build_absolute_uri("/api/photo/1/"), payload)
```

and in result you will see in GET request `"image_data": <photodata's thisdata value>,`.

But, even if you will fix the validation problems with this approach it still be a huge pain in ass as you can see from my code (this is only thing DRF can offers you when you want to "break a normal workflow", `Tastypie` offers more).

**Normalize your code and use @action (recommended)**

```
class PhotoDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoData
        fields = ("id", "thisdata")


class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_data = PhotoDataSerializer()  # or serializers.RelatedField

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("id", "user", "image_data", "test")
```

and now define a specific method **in your api's view** that you will be able to use to set the data for any photo

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers, generics
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

# ViewSets define the view behavior.


class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Photo
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

    @action(methods=['PATCH'])
    def set_photodata(self, request, pk=None):
        photo = self.get_object()
        serializer = PhotoDataSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if not photo.image_data:
                photo.image_data = PhotoData.objects.create()
                photo.save()
            photo.image_data.thisdata = serializer.data
            photo.image_data.save()
            return Response({'status': 'ok'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now you can do almost the same request as you doing now, but you have much more extensibility and division of responsibilities in code.
**See the URL**, it's appended when you have @action's wrapped method.

```
payload = {"thisdata": '{"test": "ok"}'}
resp = requests.patch(request.build_absolute_uri("/api/photo/1/set_photodata/"), payload)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent answer. I did over simplify my reasons for having thisdata as a related model for the OP. I have done some research since you posted this and understand a lot more your reasoning. This was a massive help. again thanks